# Separate event-loop for same-origin CPU intensive iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, sandbox, same-origin-policy

Let's say I have a CPU intensive iframe.
It's on the same domain as the parent page, thus cross-origin does not apply, so it shares the parent's event-loop.

Is it possible to have a separate JS context (including a separate event-loop) for the iframe, such that it doesn't block the parent's UI?

Setting the `sandbox` attribute for the `iframe` tag doesn't solve this, although the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) state that the iframe will be considered to be from a 'unique origin'.

This question is hypothetical/conceptual. I don't have a real use-case for this. Just curious.
I was wandering how sites like JSFiddle run users' code, and apparantly it runs from an iframe from a different domain (jshell.net in JSFiddle's case).

Comment: run it in a subdomain?

Comment: I'm asking specifically for iframes in the same domain

Comment: I have a use case for this, where I don't want my main event loop to be blocked or slowed down in any way by an embedded document. An existing workaround is to use a different subdomain, but I wonder if there are any other/better solutions to this.

Comment: Can you use worker threads?

Comment: Sadly not, in my case, the iframe must access the DOM after every iteration of the event loop.

Comment: @Keimeno the worker can communicate with the main process which can access DOM.

Comment: Yes, but in my case, after every event loop iteration some values must be read from the DOM, so using a web worker doesn't fit my use case.

Comment: Do you need to communicate with the iframe and vice versa?

Comment: The iframe communicates with the main document, but not the document to the iframe.

Comment: You could add a browser extension and have the iframe execute its cumbersome code in there and communicate any required data bidirectionally between the extension and the iframe.

Comment: @Keimeno, @Passiv Programmer's answer and [its linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66034016) link to an informative page: https://web.dev/origin-agent-cluster/. If you have access to the server, you can use the `Origin-Agent-Cluster` header to hint that the particular exact origin should run on its own thread. The linked page also gives decent background on the current state of threads running on same and different origin/domains.

Comment: @Steve thanks for the hint, but `Origin-Agent-Cluster` only isolates same-site cross-origin pages, not same-site same-origin, which is why it doesn't work for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

### How do Services like JSFiddle run user code in a different event loop?

They don't resolve the actual problem, they just hack their way around it, by using cross-origin iframes.

For example, this can easily be seen on StackBlitz, they create a subdomain for each execution environment.

On JSFiddle, this is a bit harder to see through at first, since their iframe doesn't have a `src` attribute set. However, the iframe is bound to a form, which ends up being another cross-origin iframe.

### Workaround - Web Workers

As others have mentioned correctly, you can use web workers, to generate a new JS context, and run some heavy calculations there.

This works, since web workers run in isolated threads ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API)).

### Workaround - Running code in smaller chunks

As others have mentioned as well, you get a performance increase by running code in smaller chunks. Take the following example:

```js
const array = [ ... ]; // array with hundreds of items
const result = [];

const stepByStepCalculation = () => {
  if (array.length) {
    result.push(doExpensiveCalculation(array[0]));
    array.shift();
    requestAnimationFrame(stepByStepCalculation);
  }
}

stepByStepCalculation();
```

Now, after every iteration of the event loop, one item of our array is being processed - step by step.

Also, using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval` or `setTimeout` has the advantage, that it will be called after every event loop iteration, and not after ~4ms, making it much faster.

### The problem with our workarounds

Our workarounds only work, if our expensive tasks, don't have to constantly read from the DOM.

**This is a big problem**, if our same-origin iframe has expensive JavaScript animations. It will heavily interfere and may cause lags in the UI.

### Summarising

Moving calculations into worker threads, or doing them step by step to reduce the load, works.

However, to your main question, we can't create a separate JS context (as of right now) for same-origin iframes. Online JS shells tackle this problem by using cross-origin iframes.

It would be interesting to see, if we can somehow run JavaScript code in the compositor or raster thread, since they should have access to our DOM, unlike web workers.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is single threaded. One way of executing tasks in other threads are web-workers. However they cannot access the DOM.

If you have a really intensive task that blocks your UI you could divide that tasks into chunks with timeouts in between.
Timeouts don't block other code from executing. So if you are smart about it this technique can be used to create time-windows for the UI to respond.

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449265/does-iframe-runs-on-the-same-thread-as-the-owner) (and answer) deals with a very similar problem.

Comment: I agree with you, that this is no answer to the suggested solution: creating a seperate js context. However the question expresses (hypothetical) problems with unresponsive UI. And those could be reduced with my solution

Comment: The linked answer on the `Origin-Agent-Cluster` header is particularly interesting, and seems to partially address the question and the bounty. The implication in the question is that different domain/origin iframes can be out-of-process iframes which run on a different threads, but same domain/origin iframes don't normally do this. Using the `Origin-Agent-Cluster` header hints that same-site cross origin frames should run on separate threads. If the iframe is the exact same origin though, it still won't run on a separate thread.