# Iframe content loading process

Tags: html, iframe

Having following code

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="..."></iframe>

<script>
document.getElementById('myframe').onload = function() {
  alert('myframe is loaded');
};
</script>
```

i wonder how does the browser processes an iframes? Does it load the iframe content in the separate thread? If so is it run synchronously with the main thread?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does iframe runs on the same thread as the owner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449265/does-iframe-runs-on-the-same-thread-as-the-owner)

Answer (score 0):

That depends stronly to the browser. Internet Explorer for example starts a seperated thread for each tab you open, some might do that otherwise. Actually, some browsers support specially secured threads for frames: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/oop-iframes

So, which browser are you asking for especially?

Answer (score 0):

The iframe is loading sync with the main website. If you want to load the content of the main site first

```
<body onload="javascript:...">
```

Comment: @Yingrjimsch "The iframe is loading sync with the main website" does it mean that the main thread waits for the iframe loading thread to finish the loading?

Comment: @Mulligun81 it waits till the iframe is loaded but not till the content of the iframe is loaded. that means you can isert an iframe, as example a video, and it loads sync the front image and the video player, but not necessairy the video.

Comment: @Yingrjimsch If i'm right that the content of the iframe is loaded independently and async in an extra thread?