# Assigning load event to an Iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Having following code

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="..."></iframe>

<script>
document.getElementById('myframe').onload = function() {
  alert('myframe is loaded');
};
</script>
```

Am I right that the iframe is loaded in the separate thread and so its possible that the alert may not fire because iframe content may load before we assign onload event handler in the script running the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way also.  iframe is loaded in the main thread / process, not a separate one. Your alert will come up once it is loaded.

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="..." onload="javascript:alert('myframe is loaded');"></iframe>
```

Comment: If i get it right that the iframe tag is loaded in the same main thread with the tags order of the site while the content of the iframe is loaded independently and async in an extra thread?

Comment: No, check this for classic behavior of iframe. http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-performance Now, newer browsers like chrome have bettered their implementation for loading iframe content. So, you will need to search this separately for current browser implementations.

Comment: I'm really confused right now. There are two similar questions: [q1]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341015/iframe-loading-and-the-main-site and [q2]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978160/iframe-content-loading-process. In the first one the user _Sudeep nayak_ answer clearly states that the iframe is loaded in a separe thread. Moreover in the q2 _Yingrjimsch's_ answer also suggests that the iframe is loaded in a separe thread. So what's the final answer?

Comment: Every browser has allowed list of connections per host-name server. iframe shares this with the main page. Your alert is attached to HTML component IFRAME, it will fire once it is loaded. You can read more about iframe behavior here. https://books.google.co.in/books?id=E7p-07kNfXYC&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&dq=chrome+iframe+load&source=bl&ots=UObpOKiaIn&sig=LT7seXbT-vayoymHOz3V-hwd5QQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvpte3n5vXAhUEHZQKHXYADHg4ChDoAQg6MAM#v=onepage&q=chrome%20iframe%20load&f=false

Comment: The thing you are calling thread is actually a nested browsing context which presents its own document and its active session but shares the connections per host name with the parent. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html