# How to force Chrome's "site isolation" for an iframe served on different host but same second-level domain?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I have a page served at http://foo.example.com/page, that embeds an iframe served at http://bar.example.com/iframe.
For performance reasons, I want to use Chrome's "site isolation" (enabled by default since Chrome 67) to render the iframe in a different thread than the main page.

However, this "site isolation" behavior only seems to fire if the main page and the iframe are served on different 2nd level domains (e.g foo.example.com and bar.otherexample.com)

The debug page at chrome://process-internals/#web-contents shows the following :

If page on foo.example.com / iframe on bar.otherexample.com :

```
Frame: locked, site:http://example.com/ | url: http://foo.example.com/page
└ Frame: locked, site:http://otherexample.com/ | url: http://bar.otherexample.com/iframe
```

The two frames have a different 'site' --> I can see the separate "Subframe: site:http://otherexample.com/" process for the iframe in Chrome's Task Manager.

If page on foo.example.com / iframe on bar.example.com :

```
Frame: locked, site:http://example.com/ | url: http://foo.example.com/page
└ Frame: locked, site:http://example.com/ | url: http://bar.example.com/iframe
```

The two frames have the same 'site' --> no "Subframe" process for the iframe.

Is there any way I can hint Chrome to see foo.example.com/page and bar.example.com/iframe as being different "sites" ?

(FWIW, on other random tabs that happen to be open in my browser I do see "Subframe" processes being split for frames with 'site' being listed as https://content.googleapis.com/ or https://accounts.google.com/ - that is, taking the 3rd level domain into account. They happen to be Google URLs, though, so I don't know if this is some specific hardcoded behavior ?)

Comment: Have a look at the new (as of 2021) [Origin-Agent-Cluster](https://web.dev/origin-agent-cluster/) header. I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66034016/11950764